# Find velocity using integration method or relative velocity approach

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, integration, relative-motion

[image]

In the diagram shown below, jeep moves with a speed of 60kmph and the car's velocity as observed from the moving jeep is 20kmph. we need to find the velocity of the car. I used relative velocity concept and got Vjc = Vj - Vc. Using the magnitudes, we can get the value of Vc = sqrt(3200). But the actual solution uses calculus method and he gets an answer of 70kmph. What limitation in this problem, avoids the usage of relative velocity?

Comment: It is not clear to me what "the velocity of the car as observed from the jeep" is supposed to mean (other then the relative velocity between the objects). Perhaps some kind of apparent speed is meant (e.g. the component perpendicular to the axis of sight)? I guess this is a school or university assignment? So perhaps you should ask your teacher/instructor/... for clarification?

Comment: its the relative velocity of the car as observed from the jeep

Comment: This statement does not make sense: What does "as observed from" mean. You say it's the relative velocity (that is the velocity in the frame of the jeep), the "observed from" then again makes reference to the jeep, but I can see no way to incorporate that information. Of course it could mean some apparent speed or the component perpendicular or parallel to the line of sight, but there is no general definition of "the velocity as observerd from somwhere".

Comment: Ok the problem is as below: A police jeep, approaching a right angled intersection from the North, is chasing a speeding car that has turned the corner and is now moving straight East. When the jeep is 0.6km north of the intersection and the car is 0.8km to the east, the police determine with radar that the distance between them and the car is increasing at 20km/hr. If the jeep is moving at 60km/hr. at the instant of measurement, What is the speed of the car?

Comment: Well this *is* well-defined! You might want to add the original problem statement to your question. The problem statement clearly states which quantity is asked for.

Comment: The problem is not asking for the relative velocity of the car. *The rate at which the distance between them is increasing* changes as the car's position changes, and is not the same as relative velocity which is constant. Also, your calculation of relative velocity is incorrect. The vertical component of relative velocity is 60kph, so the magnitude of relative velocity must be greater than this, and there is no way it can be 20kph.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a homework-like question I will not give a full solution but only a hint in the right direction as is the policy of this site.

---

Straight forward addition of the velocities fails because the quantity asked for is the velocity projected to the line of sight between the cars (since that is the quantity the radar measurement gives).

That is $v_R = 20\,\mathrm{km/h}$ is the absolute value of the following quantity:
$$v_\text{radar}(t) = \partial_t\big(\vec r_C(t) - \vec r_J(t)\big) \cdot \frac{\vec r_C(t) - \vec r_J(t)}{\left|\vec r_C(t) - \vec r_J(t)\right|} = \vec v_\text{relative} \cdot \frac{\vec r_C(t) - \vec r_J(t)}{\left|\vec r_C(t) - \vec r_J(t)\right|}.$$
So you do not really need calculus, the relative velocity is just the difference of the velocities (as vectors!) of the car and the jeep, but you have to project that velocity to the line of sight to get the value the radar device shows and then solve the equation for $v_C$.

You can also arrive at this quantity via
$$v_\text{radar}(t) = \partial_t \left|\vec r_C(t) - \vec r_J(t)\right|,$$
that is the speed with which the distance between the cars is increasing which immediately leads to the earlier formula by applying the chain rule.

Comment: Can you provide me the full solution for the problem cited using relative velocity approach. I understood it by calculus approach

Comment: Both are equivalent, the first equation in my answer directly follows from the second. And as I stated we do not provide full solutions to homework-like problems on this site.

Comment: V radar is given as 60kmph and |rcar - rjeep| =1, but how to find relative velocity